# How to create a "Form pop up box" above a highlighted word when rightclicked in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm having quite a bit of trouble getting started with creating a chrome browser extension where if a user highlights a word, a form box appears with the highlighted word and any other information the user can add to it. The image is a mockup of what I'm trying to create. I've been following the chrome developer extension tutorials, but I'm not sure how to apply it to this. (The purpose for this box would be to later push it to a database). [Prototype Image of browser extension box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BRdn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that, you would need to do the following things:

1. Listen for right-click event. Take a look at [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and [Click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/click), you could use the following code to listen to right-click event.

   ```
   document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
       if(e.button === 2) {
           // right mouse button
       }
   }, false);
   ```
2. Get highlighted word. You could use [`window.getSelection().toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) to get that.
3. Create a popup box. In content script, you can directly manipulate the DOM in current web page, just call [`Document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to create and inject your elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a content script with something like this:

```
function getSelectedText() {
    var text = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type == "Text") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    var selectedText = getSelectedText();
    if (selectedText) {
        alert("Selected text:  " + selectedText);
    }
}, false);
```